# Spring cloud gateway support for services running on non-root URLs

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Our spring cloud gateway needs to support services located in non-root URLs. For example:

```
https://thehost/api/theservice
```

I can configure the service using SimpleDiscoveryClient and SimpleReactiveDiscoveryClient or I can create my own implementation of the discovery clients. However, no matter what I do I'm still limited by this interface:

```
ServiceInstance
```

This interface has a nice method getUri(), which default implementation implements poorly and loses everything except host, port and scheme. I can provide my own implementation, but unfortunately this method:

```
LoadBalancerUriTools.doReconstructURI()
```

which the ReactiveLoadBalancerClientFilter relies on to reconstruct URI, ignores all the complexity of the original URI and in my example results in this:

```
https://thehost:443/theresource
```

Note that it hardcodes the port for https URI as well, which is not good either.

I'd like this functionality to respect the original configuration and construct the following instead:

```
https://thehost/api/theservice/theresource
```

Is there way to achieve a proper service URL handling? Maybe there's a way to customize the behavior somehow?

Comment: Why use load balancer at all in this case?

Comment: Because we need a load balancer. It's not like there's a choice on which services we need load balancer. The filter is there for all services.

Comment: Can you show your configuration then? Load balancer only does host and port. Any path changes need to use a filter like SetPath or RewritePath

Comment: Filters are not ideal in this case since it's not some kind of business logic, it's just the root of the service, which should not be limited to <host>:<port>. It can be any URL in the real world.

Comment: That's not how spring cloud gateway works. Paths aren't part of load balancing. Services registered in service discovery (consul, eureka etc..) register a host and port.